# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, x86-64, xcode6.1, arm64

I'm using a framework which someone else has written and I've included it in my project.

I run my application with xcode 6.1, i'm getting O-linker error `'Undefined symbols for architecture arm64'`

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: The framework was probably built only for 32bit architectures.

Comment: I'm using latest sdk.

Comment: How can i make it work for arm64.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent to [thunking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk) between 64 to 32 bit code: too much has changed (see: [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)).

The only solution is get the framework author to rebuild the framework with 64 bit support. If that is not possible, then you need to replace the framework with a different framework which does support 64 bit.